# Learning the Art of Electronics - keypad schematic

Tags: keypad

The image below is an extract from the schematic for the keypad referred to on page 620 of LAoE.

What does the symbol connecting switch S4 to pin 11 of U7 and connecting pins 6 and 11 of U7 mean in terms of how to wire it up? Does this just indicate direct connections between S4 and pin 11 and between pin 6 and pin 11, with the three unfilled circles and the solid and dotted curved lines indicating the function of S4 as toggling between 10Hz and 20Hz?

[image]

Comment: The term "Art" in the title is spot on. S suggest a switch. Is that a keypad repeat (10/20Hz option?) It would help if you would show the rest of the diagram.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That'll be a 3-pin header with a jumper to connect the middle pin to either side. It's, effectively a single-pole, double-throw switch.

[image]

In your example the wire from the right will connect to the centre pin and the outer pins will connect to FAST (6) and SLOW (11).